# What does イケボ mean?

Tags: translation, meaning

A friend told me it means "sexy/good looking" but I'm not sure

Answer (score 11):

イケボ is a short form of either

- **イケ**メン(cool-looking-guy) + **ボ**イス(voice
- **イケ**てる(cool) + **ボ**イス(voice)

Thus, it means "the kind of voice a cool-guy has" or simply "a cool voice"
This phrase is used to describe the voice and whether the speaker is an actual イケメン does not matter.

Oh, by the way, the word イケメン it self derives from the イケてる in the second form.

[https://www.weblio.jp/content/イケボ](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%82%A4%E3%82%B1%E3%83%9C)